# How can I copy an svn external from one working copy to another?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Assume I have got ProjectA and ProjectB, bot using the same library Library1 as an external in the following tree structure:

```
ProjectA
  src
  Library1

ProjectB
  src
  Library1
```

I have already checked out a working copy of ProjectA and I want to check out a working copy of ProjectB. The connection to the server is very slow and Library1 is rather large.

It used to be possible to just copy the Library1 subdirectory from one project to the other. svn would then automatically detect that the external was already checked out and use it without transferring it again.

This stopped working when the directory structure of the working copy was changed in subversion 1.7.0.

Is there any way that I can still use the already checked out copy of Library1 to speed up checking out ProjectB?

(Of course this is not about a single check out and only two projects but many projects.)

edit: The strange things I was talking about which did not allow me to just copy Library1 subdirectory from ProjectA to ProjectB apparently are caused by TortoiseSNV. It seems to update some of the files while the copying hasn't yet finished which resulted in inconsistencies within the .svn subdirectory. After doing a directory compare with BeyondCompare and overwriting the modified files with the original, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check out the second project using `--ignore-externals`, then copy Libray1 from project 1 to project 2 (or create a symbolic link if your OS allows it). That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that I can still use the already checked out copy of Library1 to speed up checking out ProjectB?

If **source of Library1 is common** for both projects (i.e Lib stored in independent 3-rd location), current state not clean /for me/ - you'll be able to copy Library1 *subtree* from project-WC to project-WC (because target of externals is nested WC inside WC and for shared sources these WC will be identical).

AFAICS, your Libs now served from different origins, thus - can not be freely transferred between WC